# Laravel 5: inserting only if all values exist

Tags: mysql, laravel

I am posting some data to my table.

As my post data is pretty large, is there any way to check if all values are posted? Only then insert it in database.

Or perhaps try to insert it, let the database handle it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by, “check if all values are posted”? What values are you checking?

Comment: Suppose you are expecting Test1, Test2 and Test3. What happens if only Test1 and Test2 are posted? They get inserted in database, Test3 value is missing. This is what I am trying to avoid.

Comment: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation

Comment: You could just use database transactions.

Comment: don't insert data until all posts are set or posted.

Comment: @be-codified Well validate the data then?

Answer (score 1):

u can validate request with require attribute
example

```
class CreateNotebookRequest extends Request
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'modelName' => 'required',
....
```

[Read more about request validation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation)